# Search/Fetch objects on a firebase real time database

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, google-cloud-functions

I have a realtime database on Firebase that has something like:

> - Pets
>
>   - UNIQUE_ID
>
>     - name: Beethoven
>     - breed: Labrador,Golden
>     - category: Adoption, Temporally-adoption
>     - age: ...
>     - ...

Since I'm new on Firebase, I have few doubts on how to use Firebase database  that I couldn't get a clue on their documentation, can you help me?

1. I'm trying to create a Cloud Function (to be used as a REST API) where I could search across all pets from a particular category, for example, Adoption. Is that possible? I can create, update... but I don't see how I should do this search...

> ```
> var ref = admin.database().ref('/pets');
> ref.????
> ```

2. Can I create something similar as pagination from Cloud Functions against this search?
3. I'm not familiar with this type of NoSQL databases, but do I need to create an index to do those objects searchable? I'm completely lost here, too. :(
4. It is weird to use this Cloud functions to do this type of searches? Or should I use their own SDKs per each platform? Do they provide this searches too? Looks to me that it is easier to create a Cloud functions and call it from any platform as a rest call, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Your current data structure allows you to efficiently find the categories for a specific pet. It does not allow you to efficiently find the pets for a specific category. For that you'll want to add an additional data structure to your database, where you keep the pet IDs for each category. E.g. `/categories/Adoption: { UNIQUE_ID: true }`. See my longer answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Uhm... I just now realized that this only applies if `category` can contain multiple values for each pet. If that is not is the case let me know, and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I didn't follow this approach (I thought about this "fake index" as you suggest) because let's imagine that I add a "description" field where through a search, users can search if specific words are contain in this description field (search across all objects), or an adopter is looking for a pet which name was "Beethoven" but it just remembers "Beetho". My idea was to have a "search" that could do also this. As far as you said before, looks that it is not possible, right?

Comment: There's nothing fake about the index my linked answer suggests. The fact that the application code maintains it, doesn't make it any less real than an automatically maintained index. :-)

Comment: Your question covers a range of very broad topics, so it's hard to answer concisely. Doing a full-text search on Firebase is not possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-database%5d%20text%20search. But so-called prefix searches *are* possible, so "any pet whose name starts with 'Beetho'" is `[[queryOrderedByChild:@"name"] queryStartingAtValue: @"Beetho"]`.

Comment: I'm checking firestore, and I think that it fits better with my needs. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is possible, and if your goal is to create an API then you will need to use Cloud Functions for this. I would recommend that you switch from Firebase's `realtime database` to `firestore`. The realtime database is older and lacks some of the rich queries, the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) database has better support for [advanced queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)...
2. Yep, check out [these Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) for examples of pagination.
3. Not unless you get a huge data set, as a beginner, I'd recommend you not worry about indexing.
4. You can do it either way, but if you're looking for cross-platform, then you're right - creating an API like this could definitely save you some trouble down the road.